# RegEx: Match everything except a specific string

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have this long string, "The words Text and dots represent whole bunch of html code"

Input:

`TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText....."signed_request" value="Random Value" />TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText.....`

How do i match all the text before and after the string `"signed_request" value="Random Value"` but not the string itself, considering the random value
between the quotation marks,
so it would output

Output:
`TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText...../>TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText.....`

Comment: Does the string change or stay consistent? If consistent, can you not just do a simple replace of that substring? On another note, if this is **HTML**, use a parser for this task.

Comment: It's a facebook html response when launching an app. Some values do change, just like the signed request.

Comment: I'm using a web debugging proxy software called Charles and it has an html parser.

Comment: I'm trying to replace all the code before and after this "signed_request" value="Random Value" with blank which will leave me with the signed request only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Regex

```
/\s*\/>\w+|\w+(?="\S)/g
```

[Check Here](https://regex101.com/r/tJ1vJ9/6)

Thanks @dustmouse.

Comment: That includes the closing bracket.  What about: \s*\/>\w+|\w*?(?="\S)

Comment: Sorry Updated I prefer not to use `*?`

Comment: It's still not including the /> which OP wants.

Comment: Sorry my Bad I got it.